# What are each race's racial skills and how do they work?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I know in Guild Wars 2 each race has their own unique 'racial skills', but I am not sure how exactly they are unlocked/applied/used. It would be great to have this information somewhere so people can make decisions as to what race will work well with their profession.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For skill specific details this is fully covered at the Guild Wars 2 Wiki on the page [Racial Skills](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Racial_skill).  The summary from there says:

> [Racial Skills] can be equipped on the five last slots of the skill bar,
>   depending on their type. They may have various effects, such as
>   condition removing or changing to a bear form, but they are all
>   projected to be fairly weaker than their counterparts from professions
>   that are specialized in similar skills. Each race has 6 skills. Racial
>   skills will be available from the beginning of the PvE campaign

Skills in this portion of the bar are earned in a similar fashion as skills on the left. Experience and quest completion will unlock them. The first skill is usually granted soon after starting the game and is the top skill in each race from the list below.

As of pre-launch, these are the skills. Click on each race for full details on the skill and how it can be used:

### Asura

#### Utility

- Pain Inverter
- Radiation Field
- Technobabble

#### Elite

- Summon 7-Series Golem
- Summon D-Series Golem
- Summon Power Suit

### Sylvari

#### Healing

- Healing Seed

#### Utility

- Grasping Vines
- Seed Turret

#### Elite

- Summon Druid Spirit
- Summon Fern Mastiff
- Take Root

### Norn

#### Utility

- Call Owl
- Call Wurm

#### Elite

- Become the Bear (Has Auxilary Sidebar)
- Become the Raven (Has Auxilary Sidebar)
- Become the Snow Leopard (Has Auxilary Sidebar)
- Become the Wolf (Has Auxilary Sidebar)

### Charr

#### Utility

- Battle Roar
- Hidden Pistol
- Shrapnel Mine

#### Elite

- Artillery Barrage
- Charrzooka (Has Auxilary Sidebar)
- Warband Support

### Human

#### Healing

- Prayer to Dwayna

#### Utility

- Prayer to Kormir
- Prayer to Lyssa

#### Elite

- Avatar of Melandru (Has Auxilary Sidebar)
- Hounds of Balthazar
- Reaper of Grenth